# Malloc Failing on 64-Bit Ubuntu box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-management, malloc, libsvm

I am running the following code on a 64-bit Ubuntu box with 18 GB of RAM, and as you can see, my call to Malloc is failing when I try to allocate 2^31 bytes. I am not sure why this is happening, or how to fix it (i have tried compiler flags and also calloc()). I was wondering if someone can explain to me why I am not able to alloc more space on a 64-bit box and how I can fix this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "svm_model_matlab.h"
//include "svm.h"
#include <math.h>


struct svm_node
{
        int index;
        double value;
};


//#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)calloc(n,sizeof(type))
#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))

int main()
{

        int i;
        for(i =25; i< 35; ++i)
        {
                printf("2^%d %d \n", i,(long int) pow(2,i));
                svm_node* x_space = Malloc(struct svm_node,pow(2,i));
                printf("the address is %x\n", x_space);
                free(x_space);
        }


        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2^25 33554432
the address is 8513e010
2^26 67108864
the address is 6513e010
2^27 134217728
the address is 2513e010
2^28 268435456
the address is a513e010
2^29 536870912
the address is a513e010
2^30 1073741824
the address is 0
2^31 -2147483648
the address is 0
2^32 0
the address is 0
2^33 0
the address is 0
2^34 0
the address is 0
```

Update:

I found the issue I was having: I am currently running my code on EC2 on a 64-bit Ubuntu linux distro and the default linux boxes on EC2 have 0 swap space. This was causing my process to seg fault when it was requesting any amount of memory more than the physical RAM because it was not able to page. After I created a swap file, my problem went away.

Thanks for your help

Comment: printf("%d", sizeof(svm_node)) and tell us the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pow()` is a horrible way to calculate powers of 2.  Use `1 << i` instead.

Then, pick a data type big enough to hold your requested size.  Right now it's overflowing the size of `int`, and therefore trying to allocate a negative number of bytes.  That doesn't work for obvious reasons.

I suspect that `malloc(1ULL << 31)` would succeed on your system with no issues whatsoever.

Next, you're allocating far more than the 2<sup>31</sup> bytes your question mentions, you're actually trying to allocate 2<sup>i</sup> * `sizeof (svm_node)`, or about 2<sup>i+4</sup>.  The failing allocation, with `i=30`, is for roughly 16GB, which may very well be more than your free RAM.

Finally, you're getting 32-bit values when printing pointers.  Try `printf("%p", x_space);` instead.  If that still gives you 32-bit values, try using a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: thanks for your help. im going to check this out tomorrow but i did try to change the int in svm_node to long, long long, etc and i will still see the overflow. also, this is just a simple program to show to try to solve a larger issue in libsvm where my training set size is so large that I am trying to malloc ~ 2^33.1 bytes for a simulation and malloc is failing, and i am seg faulting. this is the actually issue i am trying to solve, the purpose of this simple example was to try to re-produce this problem in a more understandable format

Comment: im not sure i follow your logic here ben: you say the follow: "Next, you're allocating far more than the 231 bytes your question mentions, you're actually trying to allocate 2i * sizeof (svm_node), or about 2i+4. The failing allocation, with i=30, is for roughly 16GB, which may very well be more than your free RAM." . I do not see how your calculating this. As you can see above, the sizeof(svm_node) = 16 bytes by my calculation 2^30 1073741824 * sizeof(svm_node) = 17179869 KBs

Comment: my bad ben,2^30 1073741824 * sizeof(svm_node) = 17 GBs